# how to put an object under circular motion using centripetal acceleration and tangential velocity?

Tags: pygame, physics

I am trying to simulate circular motion in pygame by using centripetal acceleration and the tangential velocity that a revolving object have.

Each frame the program increments a given angle and uses it to find the components of velocity and acceleration.Also the initial velocity of object is towards the right direction.

The problem is that when i run the code the point around which the object is rotating seems to move slightly up each frame .

Here's the code i am using.

```
from math import cos, sin, radians, pi

import pygame as pg

width, height = 1400, 700

dis = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))

run = True

clk = pg.time.Clock()

fps = 50

gravity = 30/fps
bounse_constant = 0.9
friction = 0.999


class body:
    k = []

    def __init__(self, x, y, vel, ang, radius):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.vel = vel
        self.xvel = vel
        self.yvel = 0
        self.angle = ang
        self.radius = radius
        self.acc = 0
        print(self.angle)

    def update(self):
        self.angle += (self.vel)/self.radius# updating the angle by the angular velocity 
        self.acc = self.vel**2/self.radius
        self.yvel += self.acc*sin(self.angle + pi/2)
        self.xvel += self.acc*cos(self.angle + pi/2)
        self.x += self.xvel
        self.y += self.yvel
        
        

        self.k.append((self.x, self.y))
        if len(self.k) > 20:
            self.k.pop(0)

    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.circle(dis, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y), 1)
        pg.draw.line(dis, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y),
                     ((self.x+self.xvel*4), (self.y+self.yvel*4)))
        
        for i in range(1, len(self.k)):
            pg.draw.line(dis, (255*i/len(self.k), 255*i/len(self.k),
                         255), self.k[i], self.k[i-1], round(i/4))


obj = body(600, 300, 10, 0, 100)
while run:
    for eve in pg.event.get():
        if eve.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
    obj.update()
    obj.draw()
    clk.tick(fps)
    pg.display.flip()#comment out this whole line if you want to see the object's path
    dis.fill((0, 0, 0))
pg.quit()
```

Comment: [Why it doesn't spin in a circle? And how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883103/why-it-doesnt-spin-in-a-circle-and-how-to-fix-it/62883770#62883770)

Answer (score 0):

By changing the following lines from using `+=` to `=`, seems to fix the problem -:

```
self.x += self.xvel
self.y += self.yvel
```

to -:

```
self.x = self.xvel
self.y = self.yvel
```

Further, the full code becomes this now(Also note I changed the radius and vel to see the motion clearly and confirm the fix) -:

```
from math import cos, sin, radians, pi

import pygame as pg

width, height = 1400, 700

dis = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))

run = True

clk = pg.time.Clock()

fps = 50

gravity = 30/fps
bounse_constant = 0.9
friction = 0.999


class body:
    k = []

    def __init__(self, x, y, vel, ang, radius):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.vel = vel
        self.xvel = vel
        self.yvel = 0
        self.angle = ang
        self.radius = radius
        self.acc = 0
        print(self.angle)

    def update(self):
        self.angle += (self.vel)/self.radius# updating the angle by the angular velocity 
        self.acc = self.vel**2/self.radius
        self.yvel = self.acc*sin(self.angle + pi/2) # Changed += to =
        self.xvel = self.acc*cos(self.angle + pi/2) # Changed += to =
        self.x += self.xvel
        self.y += self.yvel
        
        

        self.k.append((self.x, self.y))
        if len(self.k) > 20:
            self.k.pop(0)

    def draw(self):
        pg.draw.circle(dis, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y), 1)
        pg.draw.line(dis, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y),
                     ((self.x+self.xvel*4), (self.y+self.yvel*4)))
        
        for i in range(1, len(self.k)):
            pg.draw.line(dis, (255*i/len(self.k), 255*i/len(self.k),
                         255), self.k[i], self.k[i-1], round(i/4))


obj = body(600, 300, 100, 0, 1000) # Changed the dimensions..
while run:
    for eve in pg.event.get():
        if eve.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
    obj.update()
    obj.draw()
    clk.tick(fps)
    pg.display.flip()#comment out this whole line if you want to see the object's path
    dis.fill((0, 0, 0))
pg.quit()
```

**Why this works?**

This is because, at all points the velocity components are what they are being set to and they are not their previous values incremented by the current values.

Comment: This code solves the above problem but when i try to change the radius it seems to change  the velocity instead (because the velocity dependent on radius ) but does not effect actual radius.